# What is the difference in meaning between `nil` and `non` in "Primum non nocere"?

Tags: adverb, definitions

The [wikipedia entry for "Primum non nocere"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primum_non_nocere) mentions that it's sometimes written as "Primum nil nocere".

I realize the shade of difference is probably pretty fine, but is one of these more correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Prīmum nōn nocēre* means "first, to not cause harm". *Nōn* negates the verb.

*Prīmum nīl nocēre* means "first, to cause harm to nothing". *Nīl* is the object of the verb.

(Note that both are infinitives rather than commands in Latin; the original context is something like "the first law of medicine is to not cause harm".)

Answer (score 9):

It's possible that *nil* is a noun here, but it's more likely that it's the adverbial *nil*, which would translate to something like "not at all."

> B. Adverb. 1. Not (as a strengthened *non*), in nothing, in no respect, not at all: “me nihil poenitet,” Plaut. Bacch. 5, 2, 63 (etc.)

So the difference between the two would be the strength of the negation. In English, you can hear the difference between these two statements:

> 1. Don't do it.
> 2. Don't even think about doing it.